# Expressão regular formatado como domínio de internet

Tags: javascript, regex, validação, domínio

Como criar uma expressão regular para validar um domínio de internet? As regras estão abaixo:

1. Tamanho mínimo de 2 e máximo de 26 caracteres;
2. Caracteres válidos são letras de "a" a "z", números de "0" a "9" e o hífen;
3. Não conter somente números;
4. Não iniciar ou terminar por hífen.

Lembrar que a validação em questão refere-se entre o início da valor e o primeiro ponto. Exemplo: **dominio**.com.br.

Será usada tanto para URL quanto para email.

Segue o código que fiz:

```
([^-](([a-zA-Z0-9]?)*([a-zA-Z-])([a-zA-Z0-9]?))+[^-])\.
```

O mais próximo que cheguei da resposta, faltam retirar os hífens no começo e fim:

```
((([\w]?)+([a-zA-Z-_])([\w]?)+){2,26})\.
```

Comment: Estas regras podem ter problemas dependendo de onde aplicar. Servem bem numa entrada de DNS, mas se for para interação com o usuário, estão erradas. São válidos caracteres acentuados e em outras linguas na entrada de dados. A conversão para [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) não é responsabilidade do usuário, e sim do sistema. Outra coisa, não pode ter dois pontos em seguida (e dois hífens em seguida normalmente só no começo do punycode). Exemplo de link que será barrado: http://www.estadão.com.br

Comment: Tem razão, @bacco. As acentuações podem (e devem) ser aplicadas, mas não tenho a mesma certeza quanto ao ponto ou hífen seguidos (programaticamente falando).

Comment: O mais próximo que cheguei da resposta, faltam retirar os hífens no começo e fim:
`((([\w]?)+([a-zA-Z-_])([\w]?)+){2,26})\.`

Answer (score 1):

Que tal:

```
^(?!\d+\.)(\w[\w\-]{0,24}\w)\.
```

- `(?!\d+\.)` é um lookahead negativo. Ele checa que o domínio não é composto apenas de dígitos.
- `\w` o primeiro caracter não pode ser um hífen, então espera-se uma letra ou um dígito.
- `[\w\-]{0,24}` após o primeiro caracter ser comprovadamente um `não hífen`, podem existir entre 0 ou 24 letras, números ou hífen.
- `\w` o último caracter também não pode ser um hífen.
- `\.` começo do resto do domínio, no qual você não está interessado.

Em `(\w[\w\-]{0,24}\w)` você espera `1 caracter não hífen` + `0 até 24 letras, números ou hífen` + `1 caracter não hífen`. Essas três regras somadas garantem que seu domínio vai ter ao menos 2 caracteres e no máximo 26.

Você pode ver a regex funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/lS9eB7/1).

**Observações:**

A regex acima não lida com letras em outros idiomas, como comentado pelo @Bacoo, porque ECMAScript 5 e para baixo não oferecem suporte nativo a regexes Unicode ([ECMAScript 6 sim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280762/5953895)).

A mesma regex poderia ser implementada em PHP (que oferece suporte a regexes Unicode) da seguinte forma:

```
^(?!\d+\.)([\p{L}0-9][\p{L}0-9\-]{0,24}[\p{L}0-9])\.
```

onde `[\p{L}0-9]` substitui `\w` para aceitar quaisquer letras em quaisquer idiomas + dígitos. Você pode ver essa regex funcionando [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/lS9eB7/2).